# Override MediaElement on top of Webview2

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I created a WPF project in which I need display two `StackPanel`s like this:

[image: Two StackPanels: One yellow StackPanel (stackPanel1) with a red StackPanel (stackPanel2 on top of it in its left half with a margin around.]

This screen is child of main Grid

`StackPanel` 1 will be displayed without any alternation of width and height and I need to display the entire second `StackPanel` on top of previous `StackPanel`. Using `Canvas` and `DockPanel` doesn't help me in this case.

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="web1">
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="MyWebView"
             Height="800" >
        </wv2:WebView2>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="videoPlayerPanel">
        <Canvas >
            <local:VideoPlayer x:Name="videoPlayer"  Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
        </Canvas>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Please click on WPF override to see the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @thatguy answer , if we use the zIndex we can overlap the element in WPF, But the question here is related to webview2 and mediaElement.
As of now webview2 not allow another element to come on top.
So there is no way to display your mediaElement on top of webview as of now.
Reffer to this Link for this issue : [Webview2 issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/356)

You can try to display mediaElement using popup but this will give other problems
I think this is the only answer to your question right now .

Comment: ZIndex-order may not work on webview that's all the summary

Comment: May be you are right, I tried with all type of Pannel , for other element I am able to overlap only issue I am facing with webview2. I will try with popup , Thanks for correct guidance

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you define the `StackPanel`s inside the `Grid` matters. The next item is displayed above the previous one. In your example, `videoPlayerPanel` will be above `web1`, because it is defined after `web1`. There are two options to alter this behavior.

1. Change the order, define `videoPlayerPanel` before `web1`, to display `web1` above `videoPlayerPanel`.

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="videoPlayerPanel">
           <Canvas >
               <local:VideoPlayer x:Name="videoPlayer"  Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
           </Canvas>
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="web1">
           <wv2:WebView2 Name="MyWebView"
                Height="800" >
           </wv2:WebView2>
       </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
   ```
2. Define the Z-Order explicitly by setting a [`ZIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Panel.ZIndex);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) for the items.

   > Gets or sets a value that represents the order on the z-plane in which an element appears. [...] The greater the value of a given element, the more likely the element is to appear in the foreground.

   ```
   <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="web1" ZIndex="1">
           <wv2:WebView2 Name="MyWebView"
                Height="800" >
           </wv2:WebView2>
       </StackPanel>
       <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" x:Name="videoPlayerPanel">
           <Canvas >
               <local:VideoPlayer x:Name="videoPlayer"  Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
           </Canvas>
       </StackPanel>
   </Grid>
   ```

The default `ZIndex` is zero, and that explains why the [order in the `Grid` matters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.Panel.ZIndex)%3Bk(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#remarks).

> Members of a `Children` collection that have equal `ZIndex` values are rendered in the order in which they appear in the visual tree. You can determine the index position of a child by iterating the members of the `Children` collection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried both ways but still I am not getting stackpanel2 on top of stackpanel1

Comment: @unkownCoder Have you tried without `wv2:WebView2` and `local:VideoPlayer`? Maybe it is related to one of those controls.

Comment: I tried that , but no result. Here video is playing but still behind the web1 stackpanel , it should come on top of web1

Comment: @unkownCoder So you removed both controls and tested it e.g. setting a background color to make both `StackPanel`s visible? What does not result mean? What exactly happened? What is displayed?

Comment: I have used the orange background for web1 and yellow background in place of videoPlayer, I can see the orange background only, when I hide the orange background yellow shows, that means still the yellow background is coming behind the orange one

Comment: one more thing to add <local:VideoPlayer> is another usercontrol

Comment: @unkownCoder Both approaches work for me as expected. Can you try this in a new, empty solution? It seems that there is something wrong that is not reprodicible with the provided code.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , but my goal is to achieve videoplayer to play on top of web1 , for reference I checked the indexof both child inside the  grid , web1 = 0 and videplayer = 1, still unable to show , please help